# Create File into system android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I don't know why since I switched to kitkat my app cannot create any file in system (This method was working on android 4.1.2). My app has su permissions, mount system as RW and READ and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions declared in manifest.
Logcats show me that it allows SU permissions but no errors.

The code that it is not working is this one below.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath().toString(), "/etc/init.d/script");
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hasta.cocoremanager"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.7" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">       
    <activity
        android:name="com.hasta.cocoremanager.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Show me the logcat and i'll tell you why.

Comment: Sure here it is. http://pastebin.com/vXgau3Pq

Comment: I see what your doing, I have an answer for you. Give me 5 mins.

Comment: Are you sure that your app has changed it's permissions? Just executing "su" has no effect on the app itself, only on the commands you execute on the shell through su have root permissions.

Comment: I have written that this method was working on android 4.1, infact before was working correctly but now (on android 4.4) not.

Comment: hmmm, just a wild guess, but isn't the constructor suppose to be `File(String path, String name);`? As in you should be doing `new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath().toString()+"/etc/init.d", "script");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the file has read/write permissions to everyone.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "chown 777 /etc/init.d/script" });
```

Now you will be able to get an instance of that file.

If the file does not exist, first run

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "echo '#' > /etc/init.d/script" });
```

EDIT: Without knowing how you want to use the file instance, i'll take a stab at it

```
File file = null;
try
{
    file = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath().toString(), "/etc/init.d/script");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Cannot get file so set permissions.
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "chown 777 /etc/init.d/script" });
    try
    {
        file = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath().toString(), "/etc/init.d/script");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // File does not exits, so create it.
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "echo '#' > /etc/init.d/script" });
        // Now set permissions.
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "chown 777 /etc/init.d/script" });
        try
        {
            file = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath().toString(), "/etc/init.d/script");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             // Should never get here.
        }    
}

// Do stuff with your file.
```

You can always do all this in your app user area and then do

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "cp " + Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/script /etc/init.d/script" });
```

A note on calling su, this syntax also works.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cp " + Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/script /etc/init.d/script");
```

Comment: The problem is that it cannot create file using "new File"

Answer (score 1):

Since 4.4.2 there are new rules for IO on the device storage:
[Article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/02/17/external-blues-google-has-brought-big-changes-to-sd-cards-in-kitkat-and-even-samsung-may-be-implementing-them/)

To put it short: Now you can only write in your app's folder.

Comment: AFAIK this can be bypassed using root permissions, and the question mentions that root credentials are used.

Answer (score -1):

Set menifest permissions that both:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Becasuse also you required the read permission for RW and READ

Comment: OQ Already states they have done so. Plus if you have implemented your su access correctly, you don't need any other permissions.

Comment: also post your menifest file

Comment: hal hal hin te chha jo upvpte aba :p